# Why am I not able to see any data on getstream.io's explorer

Tags: php, laravel, getstream-io

I've created an app called Blog on my Getstream.io account and also created a feed group called users but I'm not able to see any data on the explorer section of GetStream.io after running this code. What could be the issue?

```
$client = new \GetStream\Stream\Client('xxxxru2tf', 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.xxxx.HBAOcgggf3-xxxx');

$ericFeed = $client->feed('users', 'joe');

// Add the activity to the feed
$data = [
    "actor"=> "ho",
    "verb"=> "like",
    "object"=> "3",
    "tweet"=> "Hello world",
];

$ericFeed->addActivity($data);
```

Comment: First: your comments don't really match up with your code. Feed group "users" vs "user", user id "eric" vs "joe".

Also the app secret seems to be a base64 encoded json string? That can't be right.

Maybe it helps, maybe not.

Comment: are you searching for users:joe in the explorer?

Comment: @hannesvdvreken Sorry, forgot to remove those comments

Comment: I can't find any data there ... @TommasoBarbugli

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/PHu0z @TommasoBarbugli

Comment: @JSONBorne after "for feed:" you're supposed to type "users:joe".